# How to check if I'm running as System user in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7

I'm trying to figure out a way to check if I'm running as the system account in Windows 7. To check if I'm running as a administrator I can do this:

```
def check_admin
    if ctypes.winddll.IsUserAdmin() != 0:
        return True
```

Now that's great and all, but what if I need to go a step above that and run as root? What if I needed to access some registry keys that only system account has access to? How can I check if my application is running as the system account?

Comment: Typically, an administrator is *root* in Windows, and the only thing that runs under the System account is services which run without a user logged in. There is no *system user*, because the system is not a *user* - it's an account used by the system. Are you writing a Windows service (highly unlikely in Python)? If not, you'll never need this information.

Comment: You're wrong. Windows has a system user that can access things like the SAM database, the security HKLM keys, the file hashes. In order to dump windows credentials you have to run as a system user to get the hive files. Using psexec, if you do `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` you'll open a command prompt as system and have access to everything. However, it might be that the cmd is running as a service instead?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/120929/how-the-system-account-is-used-in-windows

Comment: *Technically,* Ken is correct: SYSTEM isn't a user.  I believe the correct term is "security principal".  Hardly matters in this context though.  You should be able to create a SID representing the SYSTEM account using ConvertStringSidToSid() and then call CheckTokenMembership() to see whether that SID is in your token.  I don't know exactly what that would look like in Python.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's actually a really good idea, I'm gonna give that a shot

Comment: @HarryJohnston I guess I should be technically saying _system account_